# Instead of having the printf function print the actual string, it is not printing anything

Tags: c, printf

*There's a problem that I've been trying to solve for more than two hours and it's really driving me to insanity.*

Instead of having the `printf` function print the actual string that is been given, it is not printing anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "readline.h"


#define MAX_WORDS 10

int compare_words (const void * p, const void * q);

int main (void) {
    char current_word[20];
    char ** words = malloc (sizeof (char *) * MAX_WORDS);
    if (words == NULL) {
        printf ("Could not allocate enough memory for the variable\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int n_words = 0, i;

    for (;;) {
        if (n_words == MAX_WORDS) {
            printf ("Cannot assign more memory to the program.\n" 
            "Proceding to display the elements in order: \n");
            break;
        }
        printf ("Enter a sentence: ");
        read_line(current_word, 20);


        if (current_word[0] != '\0') {
            *(words + n_words) = current_word;
            n_words++;
        } else {
            qsort (words, n_words, sizeof (char *), compare_words);
            break;
        }
    }

    qsort(words, n_words, sizeof(char *), compare_words);
    printf("\nIn sorted order: ");

    for (i = 0; i < n_words; i++)
        printf("%s ", *(words + i));
    printf("\n");
}

int compare_words (const void *p, const void *q) {
    return strcmp (*(char **) p, *(char **) q);
}
```

Please, I would really appreciate if anyone helps me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `read_line(..)` and does it work?

Comment: `char ** words = malloc (sizeof (char *) * MAX_WORDS);` This does not assign memory for your strings. You need to malloc when you copy. However `*(words + n_words) = current_word;` would only save the location of `current_word` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the address of the `current_word` buffer to the pointers instead of storing an address of a copy of each string.

I suggest replacing this:

`*(words + n_words) = current_word;`

with the following:

`*(words + n_words) = strdup(current_word);`

Your `malloc` is allocating memory for pointers, not for the strings pointed by the pointers. The `strdup` function of `string.h` achieves this by duplicating a string in memory and returning a pointer to it.

Comment: Hi there, I helped out with the code formatting - check edits to see one way to do it with single back ticks. Another way is to indent the whole code block by 4 spaces or to use 3 back ticks for the start/end of a code block. You'll see in the post preview how it will turn out before you post/submit the edit.

Comment: OT: write `words[n_words]` instead of `*(words + n_words)`.